# Cannot find image that is saved locally on Android - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, local-storage, png

I am currently trying to save a png to a local directory on an Android device using flutter. This code works on iOS but doesn't work on Android. I have added the following permissions to the Android Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

this allows me permission to write and write to storage.

I use the following code below to take in a png from the assets folder and save it in local storage so it can be accessed by the app in order to render it to a video:

```
Future pngToLocalFile(String fileURL) async {
  final directory = Platform.isAndroid
      ? await getExternalStorageDirectory()
      : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  var overlayContent = await rootBundle.load(fileURL);
  var overlayFile = Platform.isAndroid
      ? File(path.join(directory!.path, '${Random().nextInt(10000)}.png'))
      : File("${directory!.path}/${Random().nextInt(10000)}.png");
  overlayFile.writeAsBytesSync(overlayContent.buffer.asUint8List());

  return overlayFile.path;
}
```

However, everytime I use it, the Android device cannot find the path, resulting in:

```
Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.potterjames.ccreation/files/3115.png".
```

and the red box of death around where the image is supposed to be on screen.

I am currently trying to save a png to a local directory on an Android device using flutter. This code works on iOS but doesn't work on Android. I have added the following permissions to the Android Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

this allows me permission to write and write to storage.

I use the following code below to take in a png from the assets folder and save it in local storage so it can be accessed by the app in order to render it to a video:

```
Future pngToLocalFile(String fileURL) async {
  final directory = Platform.isAndroid
      ? await getExternalStorageDirectory()
      : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  var overlayContent = await rootBundle.load(fileURL);
  var overlayFile = Platform.isAndroid
      ? File(path.join(directory!.path, '${Random().nextInt(10000)}.png'))
      : File("${directory!.path}/${Random().nextInt(10000)}.png");
  overlayFile.writeAsBytesSync(overlayContent.buffer.asUint8List());

  return overlayFile.path;
}
```

However, everytime I use it, the Android device cannot find the path, resulting in:

```
Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.potterjames.ccreation/files/3115.png".
```

and the red box of death around where the image is supposed to be on screen.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

*** Additional ***

```
  Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () async {
                                String path =
                                    await pngToLocalFile(selectedStickerPath);

                                print(path);
                                Get.back(
                                    result: Payload(
                                  dataPath: path,
                                  height: imageHeight,
                                  width: imageWidth,
                                  child: Image(
                                    image: AssetImage(selectedStickerPath),
                                  ),
                                ));
                              },
```

This is the code that calls the function.

The path in this case is: ./assets/Black/DAYS/TUESDAY.png

And then the child of the Payload object is shown on screen.

Comment: i think your are using AssetsImage ,Imageprovider to use image here, but image is stored in mobile folder so you need to use fileImage Imageprovider. can you share the code of how you 're using the image.

Comment: I am passing a path of an image from my Assets directory:
  `String path =
                                    await pngToLocalFile(selectedStickerPath);`
and then return to the previous page with the image: 
`Get.back(result: Payload( dataPath: path, child: Image( image: AssetImage(selectedStickerPath)))),`

Comment: here is the problem AssetImage(selectedStickerPath) needs be to FileImage(selectedStickerPath) because your image is in the mobile folder, AssetImage is only used when the image is in the asset folder.

Comment: if this  ./assets/Black/DAYS/TUESDAY.png image path from your assets folder then based on error you need to check where else is image used and what image path is used for that image provider widget.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work. It works fine on iOS but with Android I am able to get a directory path in the pngToLocalFile and then it doesn't exist when called. Assetimage appears to work fine with iOS - so may you suggest other fixes? Is there something with android that I am missing? Thanks for your help